# How to Bind Single Object With Multiple RMI Servers

Tags: java, rmi

I'm new to RMI technology and facing below issue.

We have Multiple Devices of same type connected to Local System, where on each device RMI service is running on different ports.

When we are trying to connect single device to local system through RMI its working fine.
When we try to connect second device to local system, we are getting error as below -

Could you please help us to resolve below issue?

Thanks in advance.

```
    java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:601)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:198)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:322)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Naming.java:160)
        at com.rmi.server.RMIServer.exportAndBindObject(Unknown Source)
```

**Demo.java**

```
    this.myRMIServer = new RMIServer(this.RMIServerPort,this.RMIClientPort, new RMISocketFactory());
    this.helloWorld = new HelloWorld();
    this.myRMIServer.exportObject(this.helloWorld);
    this.myRMIServer.exportAndBindObject(this.rmiServiceName, this.helloWorld);
```

**RMIServer.java**

```
    public RMIServer(int port, int rmiPort, java.rmi.server.RMISocketFactory sf)
            throws RemoteException {
        this.sf = sf;
        this.rmiPort = rmiPort;
        this.regPort = port;
        synchronized (this) {
            if (registry == null)
                registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
        }
    }

    public void exportAndBindObject(String name, RemoteObject ro)
            throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException {
        exportObject(ro);
        String url = "//127.0.0.1:" + this.regPort + "/" + name;
        Naming.rebind(url, ro);
    }
```

Comment: I can't see any relationship between your title and your question, and I am unable to believe that this code works at all on any system unless the ports are equal: see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the Registry on `port` but binding to it on `regPort`, where it isn't found.

I don't know what the purpose of `this.RMIClientPort` can possibly be. I would get rid of it. RMI servers have no business thinking about client ports.

Also you're exporting the `HelloWorld` object twice: once in Demo.java where you call `exportObject()`, and once in `RMIServer.exportAndBindObject()` where you call exportObject() again. So one of those operations must have failed, or else it didn't export anything. So there is something wrong in your `exportObject()` method.